# Finding hierarchical structure in messy energy data

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, numpy, energy

I have energy profile data (sampled at 3 hour intervals) for about 25 electricity meters in a building as pandas dataframe time series.

The meters form a hierarchical structure where the top level meters include consumption data for the lower level meters.

For example , ( a possible layered structure )

```
total
 - A
     - A1
     - A2
 - B
 - C
     - C1
     - C2 
          - C21
          - C22
```

where the lower levels add up to higher level consumption.
(eg. C = C1 + C2)

Now the task is to identify the inherent structure present in the data to use for other energy data analysis.

Is there any algorithm that can be used to detect this layered structure from messy data?
Must I exhaustively try all possible combinations for lets say 4 level structures to identify a possible match ( with some tolerance since the data is messy)?
Kindly advise certain strategies to think about this problem differently from an algorithmic perspective.

Note: The meter names are numbers and can not be interpreted to be different levels directly. I do not have a metering strategy . The magnitude of energy consumption varies (for eg. it may well be the case that A2 > C (in the above fig.)) Put in a better way , the hierarchy can only represent relative magnitudes between levels.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you say, sorry. What does your input data contain ? What can you match to what ?

Comment: Input Data is just 3 hour interval energy data values indexed by timestamp. So there would be 365(days) * 8 (number of 3hr intervals in a day) entries in units kWh for each of the 25 meters. Of course to identify the potential hierarchical structure , I was thinking of a rudimentary approach of getting yearly consumption per meter to use to identify the structure. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'What can you match to what ? ' .   Kindly elaborate.

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you receive values from the individual 25 meters ?

Comment: Yes. I do. For each meter , I would have 365*8 values.  This might be the typical structure of entries as a pandas dataframe : [(TimeStamp(14-08-2018 09:00:00) , 17.5) , (TimeStamp(14-08-2018  12:00:00) , 34.3),......for the whole year]. That is a tuple-like structure with timestamp and associated electricity reading.

Comment: So if you have all values, why worry ???

Comment: So , I have 25 meters which are hierarchically organized in some unknown manner since their names are not indicative of what they are metering. I wish to determine this hierarchy. All data is available but the organization is not so  clear.

Comment: Try DFS. Your `A,B,C` are root nodes. Beneath them are their children. I had a similar type of structure which I wanted to flatten and I used a modified DFS for this.

Answer (score 2):

This general problem is very close to [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM), unfortunately a solution has not been found with a complexity less than quadratic.

It is likely that your best solution won't be much better than exhaustively trying combinations, however with `n = 25` that shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: Hmm. How do I pose this as an algorithmic problem?  Do I just find the average yearly consumption per meter (and assuming the hierarchy has a maximum depth of 5) find a way to generate iteratively all possible 5-level combinations as some sort of nested list structure and test if it adds up to some tolerance?

Comment: Also , is there any package/library/machine-learning tool or whatever that can be used to automate this ? Pardon my lack of knowledge in this regard.

Comment: I would sort all data points into an array, and then iterate through (starting with one value as the min value in the array, and the other value < the max value - min value) until you find a pair which matches the max value, then remove the max value from the array, as its been 'solved', and keep going down. Machine learning would be very over engineered unless you had big problems with erogenous/inaccurate data. I'd guess you could write this very easily in less than 100 lines of python

Comment: Fair enough. Of course the number of levels, the number of meters per level(top and lower levels) may vary quite a bit between the levels. So i guess you would not just generate pairs but also triplets , quadruplets etc. to identify this. Anyways your suggestions are giving me ideas for a solution. Thanks.